# The "Last Active" feature seems to be off

Tags: bug

I recently answered a question on SO, checked the profile of the OP, and saw that the person was supposedly last seen 12 minutes before posting [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67736033/how-to-update-dataframe-ix-code-when-refering-to-dates/67736285#67736285).

Please see below:
[image: Here's the question]
[image: And here's the user's profile]

Is this a bug? Or am I misunderstanding "Last Seen"?

Comment: Maybe they used a bot to post that question?

Comment: [Maybe it was caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: Hey, it's been marked as a duplicate. I checked the answer, and I *was* misunderstanding "Last Seen". :)